# How to initialize an array of pointers (or do I need to do so at all)?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

It's for my college exam, so don't ask why I'm not using advanced stuff in C++.

This is a console app. The problem to solve is to write missing functions inside defined structures. It is simulation of entrance exam so there's this question struct that has its attributes as follows:

```
char* _txtOfQuestion;
char* _answers[10];     //max 10 answers
int _correct;           //location of the correct answer
int _points;            //no. of points
```

Now, I need to implement the function `Create()` of this struct, which is responsible for initialising all the structure attributes.

I thought the parameters should be:

```
Create(char* text, char* answers[], int posOfCorrect, int points){

    _txtOfQuestion = new char[strlen(text)+1];
    strcpy_s(_txtOfQuestion , strlen(text), text);

    // now this _question[10] attribute seems to be the toughest here 
    // as it happens to be an array
    // how to initialize it here or if init. is not necessary, then
    // how to assign it to this parameter answers, to that it fits?

    // code here....

    _correct = posOfCorrect;
    _points = points;

}
```

Comment: Iterate, allocate, copy. And if you don't want C++, why tag it?

Comment: Is the exam about C or C++? They're not the same language.

Comment: @AlanStokes It's about C++. I thought the pointers are basically the same in both, hence both tags. If it would make the difference, I can remove the C tag (the mods are free to do it instead).

Comment: This code is all C, not C++. The features you're not using are not advanced stuff, they are the most basic C++ you could possibly learn and much simpler than this C memory management crap.

Comment: @Puppy Oh well, it *is* C++ - it just seems that the two have much in common. So in any case, can anyone write a reply explaining how to initialize this attribute I'm after? Thank you very much

Comment: People here do not try to help, but just to lose time, since they have a lot of it,  apparently. I have not done C++ or C for a while, but in your case `answers` passed as parameter will be a pointer to `char*` elements. It depends if memory has already be allocated or not, or if you need to allocate it for a specific amount of `char*`...

Comment: @developer10: The two have almost nothing in common at all. Your educator is quite substandard and has done, at best, a terrible job. It's one thing to spew the same crap back at them to pass your exam, and another to pretend that it's correct for other people who don't know better.

Comment: @Puppy Please, do not start a useless stupid discussion between the difference of the 2 languages, which are similar in some cases, but not the same, ok, we have understood all that.

Comment: @Puppy I'm pretty sure this is C++, unless they're lying to us on college. How about this: Since I actually don't care if it's C++ or anything else, how about you show me how'd you do it in C? I'm sure it will work for me.

Comment: @developer10 Yes, this is valid C++, and don't bother about these controversial guys.

Comment: `_txtOfQuestion = new char[strlen(text)+1];` looks like C++ to me.  `new` will not compile in `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    if (answers[i] != nullptr)
    {
        _answers[i] = malloc(strlen(answers[i])+1);
        strcpy(_answers[i], answers[i]);
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

of course you can omit nullptr check.
Is that helpful?

Comment: Yeah, someone already mentioned iterating, I guess that's what I need. I will later resume coding and accept this answer should it work. Thank you!

Comment: Better to give `_answers[i]` a value for all 10 indices even if `answers[i]` is short.

Comment: or throw an exception :-) but you're right- that's what I meant when I wrote that nullptr check can be omitted

Comment: Copying a pointer value instead of a string itself won't yield any good. Use `malloc` and `strcpy`. Have to downvote it, sorry.

Comment: sure. I fixed this, maybe now it's better

Comment: What is the point of checking `if (answers[i]) != nullptr)`? Randomly having `answers[i]` be a `nullptr` means there is no need for initialization and copying the answer? Also use `new` instead of `malloc`.